# Why does html { height:100% } not work when address bar is hidden?

Tags: android, html, mobile

I have the following html:

```
<html style="height:2000px">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
        html { height: 100%; background: orange; }
        body { height: 100%; background: green; position: relative; }
        #b { position: absolute; bottom: 0 }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" id="b">click me</button>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('b').onclick = 
            () => document.documentElement.style.height = null;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I uploaded it to [this link](http://misc.venus.tandola.com/html-height.htm). Open it in Chrome or Opera on Android. Scroll down to the 'click me' button, ensuring that the address bar gets hidden as you scroll down, and click on it. You should get this:

[image]

How does this make any sense - why is it not green all the way down?

Comment: in google chrome dev tool- device tool bar works perfect. What browser you use on the mobile? and whats the resolution?

Comment: Of course, because the dev-tools doesn't have an address bar - see the question heading. I'm using Chrome or Opera on Android, Galaxy S9.

Comment: @wezten it works perfectly fine for me [here look](https://ibb.co/wShC1mk).

Comment: What browser & OS is that? Are you sure you clicked the button 'click me'? Also, ensure that the address bar was displaying initially after page load.

Comment: Chrome, Android. I clicked the button too but the same result. Yes the address bar was displaying initially.

Comment: Hmmm, I see this issue every time, in both Chrome & Opera.

Comment: I can reproduce it on [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/) . Click on Live, enter [my link](http://misc.venus.tandola.com/html-height.htm) from the question, and select Chrome on Samsung Galaxy S9. Scroll down, and click on the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/12/url-bar-resizing explains that `height:100%` on `<html>` gives it the same height as the ICB (Initial Containing Block), and the height of the ICB is the 'smallest possible viewport', which is the height with the address bar showing. Even when the address bar is hidden, the height of the ICB does not change, explaining all the orange at the bottom of my screenshot.

Using '100vh' gives it the viewport height when the address bar is hidden, and it also does not change when the address bar becomes visible.

So if you wish the height to adapt to whether the address bar is visible or not, JS must be used.